# SQL Server 2012 - How can I update a colum with grouped running numbers based on other column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that looks like :

```
INDEX       IsValid                StopPoint              TripSubId
----------- ---------------------- ---------------------- -----------
7           7                      NULL                   NULL
9           9                      NULL                   NULL
10          10                     NULL                   NULL
13          13                     13                     NULL
18          18                     NULL                   NULL
25          25                     NULL                   NULL
26          26                     NULL                   NULL
27          27                     NULL                   NULL
28          28                     NULL                   NULL
29          29                     29                     NULL
30          30                     NULL                   NULL
31          31                     NULL                   NULL
32          32                     NULL                   NULL
33          33                     NULL                   NULL
34          34                     34                     NULL
35          35                     NULL                   NULL
36          36                     NULL                   NULL
37          37                     NULL                   NULL
39          39                     NULL                   NULL
40          40                     NULL                   NULL
```

And I want to update the last column like this :

```
INDEX       IsValid                StopPoint              TripSubId
----------- ---------------------- ---------------------- -----------
7           7                      NULL                    1
9           9                      NULL                    1
10          10                     NULL                    1
13          13                     13                      1
18          18                     NULL                    2
25          25                     NULL                    2
26          26                     NULL                    2
27          27                     NULL                    2
28          28                     NULL                    2
29          29                     29                      2 
30          30                     NULL                    3
31          31                     NULL                    3
32          32                     NULL                    3
33          33                     NULL                    3
34          34                     34                      3
35          35                     NULL                    4
36          36                     NULL                    4
37          37                     NULL                    4
39          39                     NULL                    4
40          40                     NULL                    4
```

Rule is, I want the number to increase once I reach a point which is not null on column `StopPoint`.

How can I do it?

Comment: what version of SQL Server do you work on?

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT 
    *,
    COUNT(StopPoint) OVER (ORDER BY [INDEX] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS Cnt
FROM YourTable
)
UPDATE T 
SET TripSubId = Cnt + CASE WHEN StopPoint IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fcd63/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
update temp set
    TripSubId = C.cnt
from temp as T
    outer apply (select count(TT.StopPoint) + 1 as cnt from temp as TT where TT.INDEX < T.INDEX) as C
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to store the column in the database, or could you just calculate it when selecting?

```
SELECT o.INDEX, o.IsValid, o.StopPoint,
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable i where i.INDEX <= o.INDEX AND i.StopPoint IS NOT NULL ) as TripSubID
FROM myTable o
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
 [INDEX] , [IsValid], [StopPoint]
, [TripSubId] = 
    (SELECT COUNT(*)  + 1 
     FROM tbl t2 
     WHERE t2.[INDEX] <=  t.[INDEX] AND StopPoint IS NOT NULL)
FROM tbl t
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44496/4)

Answer (score 1):

Here's your data

declare @tmpTable table (
    Idx int,
    IsValid int,
    StopPoint int,
    TripSubID int

)

```
INSERT @tmpTable (Idx,IsValid,StopPoint,TripSubId)
SELECT 7,7,NULL,NULL union
SELECT 9,9,NULL,NULL union
SELECT 10,10,NULL,NULL union
SELECT 13,13,13,NULL union
SELECT 18,18,NULL,NULL union
SELECT 25,25,NULL,NULL union
SELECT 26,26,NULL,NULL union
SELECT 27,27,NULL,NULL union
SELECT 28,28,NULL,NULL union
SELECT 29,29,29,NULL union
SELECT 30,30,NULL,NULL union
SELECT 31,31,NULL,NULL union
SELECT 32,32,NULL,NULL union
SELECT 33,33,NULL,NULL union
SELECT 34,34,34,NULL union
SELECT 35,35,NULL,NULL union
SELECT 36,36,NULL,NULL union
SELECT 37,37,NULL,NULL union
SELECT 39,39,NULL,NULL union
SELECT 40,40,NULL,NULL;
```

and your update

```
with cte as (
    select StopPoint,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StopPoint) TripSubID
    from @tmpTable
    where StopPoint is not null
)

update @tmpTable
set TripSubID=(select MIN(TripSubID) from cte where a.Idx<=cte.StopPoint)
from @tmpTable a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t table (
   indx      int
 , isvalid   int
 , stoppoint int
 , tripsubid int
);

INSERT INTO @t (indx, isvalid, stoppoint, tripsubid)
  VALUES ( 7,  7, NULL, NULL)
       , ( 9,  9, NULL, NULL)
       , (10, 10, NULL, NULL)
       , (13, 13, 13  , NULL)
       , (18, 18, NULL, NULL)
       , (25, 25, NULL, NULL)
       , (26, 26, NULL, NULL)
       , (27, 27, NULL, NULL)
       , (28, 28, NULL, NULL)
       , (29, 29, 29  , NULL)
       , (30, 30, NULL, NULL)
       , (31, 31, NULL, NULL)
       , (32, 32, NULL, NULL)
       , (33, 33, NULL, NULL)
       , (34, 34, 34  , NULL)
       , (35, 35, NULL, NULL)
       , (36, 36, NULL, NULL)
       , (37, 37, NULL, NULL)
       , (39, 39, NULL, NULL)
       , (40, 40, NULL, NULL);

SELECT t.indx
     , t.isvalid
     , t.stoppoint
     , Dense_Rank() OVER (ORDER BY y.stoppoint)
FROM   @t As t
 CROSS
 APPLY (
        SELECT Coalesce(Max(stoppoint), -1) As stoppoint
        FROM   @t
        WHERE  stoppoint IS NOT NULL
        AND    indx < t.indx
       ) As y
ORDER
    BY t.indx;
```